# Exporting unity features to your game

Tags: unity, export

I wonder if it is possible to export Unity features to my game.

For example if I want user to be able to modify scale or rotation of object, do I have to scritp it myself or can i somehow export it ?
Same question about some simple texturing, adding lights, etc.

Comment: So you want your game to be an editor of some sorts / have editor functions in your game?

Comment: Exactly, I want my game to have some kind of customizing interior of the room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you will have to implement this yourself.

While you can access some of the classes from the `UnityEditor` namespace while testing in the editor, they are unavailable when you actually build the game. The result will be that the game will fail to compile.

So if you want any editing functionality within your game, you need to build that yourself using the [Unity UI system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html) with [the widgets it provides](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIInteractionComponents.html).